# rails server argument error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

After installing devise with `devise_install` successfully, when restarting the server, I am getting the following error. Please help me. I have gone through number of questions and I am not getting correct response .

Error :

```
bfmt048@bfmt048-System-Product-Name:~/demo$ rails s
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.0.0 application starting in development on  zero.zero.zero.zero:threethousand
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/home/bfmt048/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activemodel-4.0.0/lib/active_model/validations/format.rb:46:in `check_options_validity': The provided regular expression is using multiline anchors (^ or $), which may present a security risk. Did you mean to use \A and \z, or forgot to add the :multiline => true option? (ArgumentError)
    from /home/bfmt048/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activemodel-4.0.0/lib/active_model/validations/format.rb:20:in `check_validity!'
    from /home/bfmt048/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activemodel-4.0.0/lib/active_model/validator.rb:143:in `initialize'
    from /home/bfmt048/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activemodel-4.0.0/lib/active_model/validations/with.rb:87:in `new'
    from /home/bfmt048/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activemodel-4.0.0/lib/active_model/validations/with.rb:87:in `block in validates_with'
    from /home/bfmt048/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activemodel-4.0.0/lib/active_model/validations/with.rb:86:in `each'
    from /home/bfmt048/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activemodel-4.0.0/lib/active_model/validations/with.rb:86:in `validates_with'
    from /home/bfmt048/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activemodel-4.0.0/lib/active_model/validations/format.rb:111:in `validates_format_of'
    from /home/bfmt048/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/devise-1.1.rc0/lib/devise/models/validatable.rb:20:in `block in included'
    from /home/bfmt048/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/devise-1.1.rc0/lib/devise/models/validatable.rb:17:in `class_eval'
    from /home/bfmt048/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/devise-1.1.rc0/lib/devise/models/validatable.rb:17:in `included'
    from /home/bfmt048/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/devise-1.1.rc0/lib/devise/models.rb:63:in `include'
    from /home/bfmt048/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/devise-1.1.rc0/lib/devise/models.rb:63:in `block (2 levels) in devise'
    from /home/bfmt048/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/devise-1.1.rc0/lib/devise/models.rb:63:in `each'
    from /home/bfmt048/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/devise-1.1.rc0/lib/devise/models.rb:63:in `block in devise'
    from /home/bfmt048/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/devise-1.1.rc0/lib/devise/models.rb:77:in `devise_modules_hook!'
    from /home/bfmt048/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/devise-1.1.rc0/lib/devise/models.rb:62:in `devise'
    from /home/bfmt048/demo/app/models/user.rb:4:in `<class:User>'
    from /home/bfmt048/demo/app/models/user.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/bfmt048/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:423:in `load'
    from /home/bfmt048/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:423:in `block in load_file'
    from /home/bfmt048/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:615:in `new_constants_in'
    from /home/bfmt048/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:422:in `load_file'
    from /home/bfmt048/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:323:in `require_or_load'
    from /home/bfmt048/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:462:in `load_missing_constant'
    from /home/bfmt048/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:183:in `const_missing'
    from /home/bfmt048/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:226:in `const_get'
    from /home/bfmt048/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:226:in `block in constantize'
    from /home/bfmt048/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:224:in `each'
    from /home/bfmt048/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:224:in `inject'
    from /home/bfmt048/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:224:in `constantize'
    from /home/bfmt048/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:66:in `constantize'
    from /home/bfmt048/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/devise-1.1.rc0/lib/devise/mapping.rb:75:in `to'
    from /home/bfmt048/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/devise-1.1.rc0/lib/devise/mapping.rb:68:in `modules'
    from /home/bfmt048/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/devise-1.1.rc0/lib/devise/mapping.rb:81:in `strategies'
    from /home/bfmt048/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/devise-1.1.rc0/lib/devise.rb:166:in `register'
    from /home/bfmt048/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/devise-1.1.rc0/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:93:in `block in devise_for'
    from /home/bfmt048/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/devise-1.1.rc0/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:92:in `each'
    from /home/bfmt048/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/devise-1.1.rc0/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:92:in `devise_for'
    from /home/bfmt048/demo/config/routes.rb:3:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/bfmt048/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:316:in `instance_exec'
    from /home/bfmt048/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:316:in `eval_block'
    from /home/bfmt048/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:294:in `draw'
    from /home/bfmt048/demo/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/bfmt048/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:222:in `load'
    from /home/bfmt048/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:222:in `block in load'
    from /home/bfmt048/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/bfmt048/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:222:in `load'
    from /home/bfmt048/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
    from /home/bfmt048/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
    from /home/bfmt048/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
    from /home/bfmt048/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
    from /home/bfmt048/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
    from /home/bfmt048/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `call'
    from /home/bfmt048/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `execute'
    from /home/bfmt048/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in `updater'
    from /home/bfmt048/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:6:in `execute_if_updated'
    from /home/bfmt048/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:69:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    from /home/bfmt048/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /home/bfmt048/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /home/bfmt048/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /home/bfmt048/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc2/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /home/bfmt048/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc2/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/bfmt048/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc2/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /home/bfmt048/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc2/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/bfmt048/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc2/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
    from /home/bfmt048/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc2/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/bfmt048/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc2/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
    from /home/bfmt048/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /home/bfmt048/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
    from /home/bfmt048/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /home/bfmt048/demo/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/bfmt048/demo/config.ru:3:in `require'
    from /home/bfmt048/demo/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from /home/bfmt048/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
    from /home/bfmt048/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
    from /home/bfmt048/demo/config.ru:in `new'
    from /home/bfmt048/demo/config.ru:in `<main>'
    from /home/bfmt048/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
    from /home/bfmt048/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
    from /home/bfmt048/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /home/bfmt048/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    from /home/bfmt048/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
    from /home/bfmt048/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:48:in `app'
    from /home/bfmt048/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
    from /home/bfmt048/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:75:in `start'
    from /home/bfmt048/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:78:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/bfmt048/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `tap'
    from /home/bfmt048/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: try upgrading your version of Devise.  as you are using version 1.1, you need to be using the latest version.  IF you have a version specified in your Gemfile, try removing it and running bundle update

Comment: Did you upgrade from a previous version of rails?

Comment: Can you show us the command at `app/models/user.rb:4`? And parts of your Gemfile pertaining to devise plugins?

Answer (score 4):

```
ArgumentError: The provided regular expression is using multiline anchors (^ or $),
which may present a security risk. Did you mean to use \A and \z,
or forgot to add the :multiline => true option?
```

This error occurs when trying to upgrade from previous version of rails to rails 4.0.0.

**Regexp validation for validates_format_of.**

If you don’t expect multiline incoming data, you need to replace all the “^” with “\A” and all the “$” with “\z”. If you expect multiline strings, just specify the multiline: true option.

Source: http://dev.mensfeld.pl/2013/07/upgrading-to-rails-4-0-from-rails-3-2-test-case-part-ii-assets-models/

Not sure of the specific reason for your error, but I would try updating devise to latest version which supports rails 4.0.0.

Comment: I've update devise to the latest version (3.2.2) and I am still getting this error.

Comment: I finally found out what was the problem. There was a email validation regexp in one of my devise user models which was using multiline anchors. Changing it solved the problem. The version of devise didn't really matter.

Comment: Yeah, it had to be something with regexp.

Answer (score 1):

this is a new check in rails 4. why are you using such an old devise version (and why an rc?).  just use the most recent release by putting

```
gem "devise", "~> 3.0.3"
```

in your Gemfile

Comment: even after updating my gem to devise 3.0.3 , and bundle install successfull , but getting an error same like above when generate rails s

Answer (score 0):

It's not safe to use ^ and $ since $ matches \n (new-line characted) which has the possibility to enter an email like "test123@example.com\n< script>/* ... */< /script >"

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#format

So if we use ^ and $ to match the end or beginning of an expression then the above is likely to pass the filter and any malicious code can be passed in with the email entered.

We can either use the /A, /Z option to specfy the beginning and end of a line, instead of ^ and $, or else we can set the :multiline option to true

> eg: validates :content, format: { with: /^Meanwhile$/, multiline: true }

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#regular-expressions

Comment: It appears that Devise used these less safe anchors in earlier versions. When upgrading the app, Devise will need to be upgraded as well. I had the same issue upgrading a dusty old app to Rails 4.

Comment: yes same here while we upgraded our devise version to 3.2.2, for building API we had to manage TokenAuthenticatable ourself as it was prone to timing attacks